# Verb to use when someone makes you 'hear' something

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'll explain my question with a example : 
A person has a picture, and an audio clip on their phone.
After seeing the picture, i can say "He/She **showed** me the picture."
What is a similar word for the audio clip i heard?

Comment: 1-He showed me the picture and played me the audio clip. 2-He showed me the picture and let me hear the audio clip. 3- He showed me the picture and made me hear the audio clip.

Comment: "Played" is the most common; "shared" would also be possible, but the connotation there is that the two people are not in the same place, listening at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. He played the sound file for me to listen to.
2. He handed me the device with the sound file ready to be played.
3. He allowed me to listen to the file he had on his device.

Comment: Options 2. 3. are not even close to the 'showed' used for the picture. The first option, 'played it', sounds closer, but it does not imply anyone actually having heard it unless followed by 'for me' or 'for the crowd' etc. But unless we get a better suggestion, i think thats what we'll have to settle on. :)

Answer (score 1):

He ***showed me*** the picture and ***played me*** the audio clip.

Here are **[*Google Ngrams*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He%20played%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20played%20me%3B%2Cc0)** for ***["he played me"](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=AtEYBrGpGZwC&pg=PT90&dq=%22he%20played%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-29ruurXTAhUDs48KHSNtC6QQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22he%20played%20me%22&f=false)***.

Comment: Except that "played me" has another entirely different meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks exactly... thats y i was waiting for another option. Thanks for the Ngrams link.. :)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, however, @displayname provided the same answer before you.. so i am accepting the first answer...

Comment: @HotLicks - Not in this context.  Not remotely.  I find this comment completely unproductive.

Answer (score 0):

Did she make him hear the audio clip ?

> She made him hear the audio clip.

Comment: This is a suggestion and  should be a comment rather than an answer. Also it implies a level of compulsion that is absent in the original.